# Flash and AIR technologies on apple's computers

Tags: macos, flash, air, osx-leopard

I saw couples of weeks ago some notes in adobe AIR website that they said adobe AIR will not be supported on Apple's devices like mac-book-pro, and am working on an application that will be made using adobe AIR and flash technologies and I have to make sure that it will works on apples computers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash and AIR are completely compatible with Apple's full-fledged computers. These are anything that run Mac OS X (to say nothing of OS version requirements), like Mac Pro, MacBook (Pro), MacBook Air, iMac, Mac Mini.

Flash and AIR are *not* compatible with iOS devices: iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad.